# is there a way of disable universal links for pinterest on ios9?

Tags: html, ios9, pinterest

Apple introduced on IOS9 the "Universal Links".

If a user has, for instance, Pinterest installed, and I have a Pinterest "pin it" button on my page, once the user has clicked on it the Pinterest app should trigger, and the user continues on that app.

The problem is that the Pinterest app is not accepting the `image_url` params.

Is there a way to prevent the browser to deep link?

Here is a example of the button:

```
<a class="pinterest" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/%20button/?no_auto_redirect_or_interstitial=1&amp;amp;url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000%2Fproduct%2Flil-foxy-roxy-women%2Fknit-your-own&amp;amp;media=http:///d3fzrgzt53nwlw.cloudfront.net/app/public/spree/suite_images/19314/large/INDEX.jpg?1447070973&amp;amp;description=Lil%27%20Foxy%20Roxy%20by%20Wool%20and%20the%20Gang" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: What you're looking for is `media`. You only will use `image_url` if you're using the developer API.

Comment: I'm actually using the media param

Comment: You should go to developers.pinterest.com and create a legitimate Pin it button, rather than this hack